# BlackBerry Cell Tower Location

Tags: blackberry, geolocation, gps, location

I have successfully acquired location in my BlackBerry through the criteria;

```java
BlackBerryCriteria myCriteria = new BlackBerryCriteria(LocationInfo.GEOLOCATION_MODE)
```

The location was acquired in the following scenario:

- No mobile coverage on the BlackBerry handset
- Active internet connection
- No GPS fix

My question is **what is this location that is acquired - GPS or Cell Tower Triangulation?**

I believe since the location is acquired indoors without any GPS fix, it should be a Cell Tower location. I do not have mobile coverage yet the location is acquired. How is the cell tower information obtained then? If I was using a roaming GPRS connection, would the location obtained be any different (based on the IP settings)? For reference, below is the complete code of obtaining the location:

```java
 try
 {
     BlackBerryCriteria myCriteria = new BlackBerryCriteria(LocationInfo.GEOLOCATION_MODE);
     try
     {
         BlackBerryLocationProvider myProvider = (BlackBerryLocationProvider)
         LocationProvider.getInstance(myCriteria);
         try
         {
             BlackBerryLocation myLocation = (BlackBerryLocation)myProvider.getLocation(30000);
             double _longitude = myLocation.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude();
             double _latitude = myLocation.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude();

             setLocation(new Coordinates(_latitude, _longitude, 0.0f)); 

         }
         catch (InterruptedException e)
         {
             showException(e);
         }
         catch (LocationException e)
         {
             showException(e);
         }
     }
     catch (LocationException e)
     {
         showException(e);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your description correctly:

> ```
> No mobile coverage on the BlackBerry handset
> Active internet connection
> No GPS fix
> ```

you must have a Wi-Fi connection then (active internet, but no mobile coverage).

So, the device is then using Wi-Fi geolocation (*aka* WLAN geolocation), which was added a bit late in the development of BlackBerry Java (although, it's still been available for a while ... OS 6.0+).

http://devblog.blackberry.com/2011/09/wifi-geolocation-launch/

Obviously, the test is to turn off your Wi-Fi, and see if you still get location fixes.

Comment: I am unable to get location without WIFI. I need wifi connection to obtain the location. What is the means of getting this location?What is this based upon?Secondly this is working fine in OS 6 and onwards. However `LocationInfo.GEOLOCATION_MODE` is not supported for OS 5. What is the equivalent that I am supposed to use for OS 5? Please guide

Comment: @Sarah, please see the link I posted.  BlackBerry added `GEOLOCATION_MODE` (and `GEOLOCATION_MODE_WLAN`) in OS 6.  `GEOLOCATION_MODE` will pick whatever location fix is available.  If you don't have mobile/cellular coverage, but do have Wi-Fi, then it will pick Wi-Fi.  If you really **need** to support OS 5.0 (which is very, very old now), then you could use a 3rd-party solution.  [For example, Google has a geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/) that supports wifi location fixes.

Comment: [Here is another link](http://developer.verizon.com/content/vdc/en/verizon-tools-apis/verizon_apis/navbuilder-inside-sdk/verizon-toolsandapis-NBI-tech-resources/verizon-nbi-location-kit-api-reference.html) to a 3rd-party solution that supports Wi-Fi fixes, although that's carrier (and country) specific.

Comment: Thank you @Nate for the details. As for the Google geolocation API, I am currently using: 
`int cellID =GPRSInfo.getCellInfo().getCellId(); 
int lac = GPRSInfo.getCellInfo().getLAC(); 
String urlString2 = "http://www.google.com/glm/mmap";`
This is with Cell ID. However it fails to work. I am trying with the Google API you provided but unable to start. Kindly advice how to access Wi-Fi data for the Google API?

Comment: @Sarah, that's really a completely different question.  We shouldn't start new questions down here in the comments, because other people generally won't read them.  Your problem here was determining **where** the location data came from, and the answer is **from a Wifi location fix**.  You can post a new question, where you just show your Google API code, and ask why it's not working.  Thanks.

Comment: you are right. I have posted as a new question. Please see if you can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767618/blackberry-wi-fi-location-in-os-5