# BlackBerry Wi-Fi Location in OS 5

Tags: blackberry, geolocation, location, wifi

I have successfully acquired Wi-Fi location in my BlackBerry App built on BlackBerry JRE 6.0 through the following code:

`BlackBerryCriteria myCriteria = new BlackBerryCriteria(LocationInfo.GEOLOCATION_MODE)`

I am now trying to compile the same App in BlackBerry JRE 5.0 However, `LocationInfo` is not part of BlackBerry 5 API and so I would require another mechanism. I have come to understand that `GEOLOCATION_MODE_WLAN` is available in BlackBerry 5 only through third party application. [For example, Google has a geolocation API that supports wifi location fixes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/). However I am lost as to how to implement this in code behind. Can anybody guide so I can get a start and implement it accordingly.

Please Help!!

Comment: So, before you get into **coding** this, there is an architectural decision to make.  What are your constraints here?  What part of the world does this need to work in? (where are your users?) Can you use a geolocation service that costs money, or does it have to be completely free?

Comment: This App is targeted for users worldwide; US, Canada, UK, Afghanistan, Iraq, Jordan, Pakistan etc. Since this app is targeted for employees of an organization, I will have to weigh the pros and cons of using a geolocation thats free and that costs money. I will make my choice accordingly. But I am open to both options.